# issue with models in relational tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, relationship

I have two tables: **demographics** and **races**.  Each Demographic needs to have one Race.  I have created a foreign key in the demographics table for race_id.
Here are the models:

```
class Demographic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :race
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :demographic
end
```

The view correctly pulls a list of races from the races table.
I think the problem is in my Demographics controller.

What is odd is that `@demographic['race_id']` always retuns nil eventhough the dump has a value.

rails = v4.0.2
ruby  = v2.0.0
psql  = v9.1

Comment: As per the given associations,you should not have `race_id` in your `demographic` table.You should have `demographic_id` in your `race` table.You are just confused.You have to read these Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, as you noted, `@demographic['race_id']` is `nil`. This results in the following code `'Demographic was successfully updated' + nil`, which if you try in irb will fail in the same way. It is expecting a string to concatenate, and gets nil, instead. You could solve it like this `'Demographic was successfully updated' + tmp.to_s`, this `"Demographic was successfully updated #{ tmp }"` or this `'Demographic was successfully updated' << tmp.to_s`. You still need to find out why it is always nil, perhaps you intend to call `@demographic.race_id`?

Comment: Yes, that keeps it from throwing the exception, but it still doesn't save the value or concatinate anything.  race_id is empty.

Comment: Have you permitted `race_id`? It's clearly coming in. Also, Huy is right, you should be able to just say race, probably, depending on your use case...

Comment: That is it!  Thank you.  I formerly called this column 'race' in the demographics table.  When I made it a foreign key it became 'race_id' but the permit statement still had 'race'.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your relationships,

```
class Demographic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :race
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :demographic
end
```

your `Race` model should have an attribute `demographic_id`, not the way you have it now where `Demographic` has a `race_id` column.. Then, to reference the race that belongs to `@demographic`, you can just do `@demographic.race`

Edit:

After reading your comment below, it sounds like you want something where if you had a race (`@race`), you can get all of its demographic `@race.demographics`. You also want a demographic instance, `@demographic`, to belong to a race so that when you do `@demographic.race`, you get the race of that demographic.

If this is true, then you want to change your relationship to:

```
class Demographic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :demographic
end
```

and in this case, it would be correct to have a `race_id` column in your Demographic model.

Comment: Pavan said the same thing, but this is so counter intuitive that I'm having a hard time accepting it.  I plan to have many ppl of differing races as demographics.  (i.e. many asians, many caucasians).  If I add a demographic_id column, then the table will either have to replicate the race or, only have one demographic per race.

Comment: @user1344643 It would be helpful if you pasted your controller code so that we can see what you're trying to do. I am trying to understand your comment above, but am unsure what `demographics` is based on your explanation.

Comment: @user1344643 I think I understand what you're trying to say now. I believe what you really want is `Demographic belongs_to race` and `Race has many demographics`. In this case, you can leave your `race_id`. I will update my answer.